# Is there a way to update a record in .NET Core for MongoDB by using entity directly just like Entity Framework update method

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework

.NET Core project

Is there a way to update a record in .NET Core for MongoDB by using entity directly just like Entity Framework update method?

Like this :

```
private IMongoCollection<T> _collection = ......GetCollection<T>("users");

_collection.UpdateOneAsync(userEntity);
```

In Entity Framework, update method is just like this. Too easy to update a record in. But I don't know how to easy and flexible update a record for MongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, there is one way to achieve what you want:

```
var user = new User { Id = 1};

var collection = database.GetCollection<User>("users");

var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(u => u.Id, user.Id);

collection.ReplaceOne(filter, user);
```